# Bypass Assets In Public Directory In Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline, asset-sync

I have a Rails 3.2 Project deployed to Heroku and using Asset Sync that has grown to a point where there are so many assets that Precompiling them on Heroku is too slow. So I'm using:

`$ rake assets:precompile`

… to compile the assets locally (with Asset Sync pushing them to an S3 bucket). Obviously this creates an `assets` folder in my public folder containing all the precompiled assets.

Now when I push to Heroku, it sees that I've precompiled my assets and skips precompilation, making my deploy much faster.

The problem comes when I go back to developing locally. Now that the assets are precompiled, Rails uses those assets and doesn't pick up changes I make to my local files. The obvious thing to do is to delete the assets, but this means that every time I push I need to first re-precompile the assets which is time-consuming.

So how can I tell Rails to ignore any assets in the public directory and use my unprecompiled local files whilst in the development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change / set the `assets_prefix` in `config/environments/development.rb`, like suggested in the  [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation):

```
config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"
```

From now on Rails checks this folder (`public/dev-assets`) in dev-mode for any precompiled assets instead of the default location (`public/assets`) - and uses your unprecompiled local files, if dev-assets is empty:

Since `rake assets:precompile` runs in production mode by default (same as `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`), compiled assets are still written to the default-location `public/assets`, but never to `public/dev-assets` - this way your dev-env won't be affected at all ...